# Where is my .bashrc file in a dd image?

Tags: mac, hard-drive, backup, bash, recovery-hd

I created an "emergency" image of my entire HD using the procedure explained in 
[Recover a dead hard drive using dd](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050302225659382).

I spent a lot of time fine tuning my .bashrc and .profile files, but I cannot find them in the image. Do you know where it should be located? I already looked in a folder with my user name and in a directory called "Mac".

UPDATE:

The output is that I have a .dmg file with thousands of crazy files and directories that I cannot mount in my mac ([How to mount a DMG image created with dd?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220754/how-to-mount-a-dmg-image-created-with-dd)), so I am using 7zip in a windows machine to explore the image file.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of 7zip exploring the raw dd file.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a find command :

```
sudo find /Volumes/YOUR_DD_NAME/* -name ".bashrc" -print; say finish
```

It's working for me with my .zshrc

[image]

Note that the command take a while, `say finish` is just more convenient ;)

Comment: Th problem is that I cannot mount the image on my mac, so I am using 7zip in a Windows machine to explore the image file.

Comment: So your .bashrc is certainly located into /Users/YOUR_NAME/.bashrc

Comment: That was my obvious guess, but there is no such directory!!!

Comment: Obviously ^^ And you can't boot on your image ? It is the more convenient way to find what you want --- EDIT : Apparently you can't :/

Comment: No, the whole thing started because I was not able to boot my mac, so I used dd on the terminal available in the recovery partition. So I have a .dmg file with a bunch of damaged files. At least I was able to recover some of my files.

Comment: Perhaps you can use a recovery tool like DataRescue.com or http://hyperlogos.org/page/Recovering-damaged-CDs-or-DVDs-Linux